# process.waitfor() and BufferReader not writing full file in console

Tags: java, process

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(propertiesMap.get("PmdBatFile"));
BufferedReader reader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String s ;
while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(s);
}
process.waitFor();
```

Here the process stops and the jvm kind of goes into deadlock after writing approx 13,000 lines in output and the file size shows 3 MB, where as it should have written almost anywhere more than 1 lack lines in the file which is more than 500 MB of file.

Is there a limit to what can be written through bufferReader?

Comment: No. The problem is probably that the process is expecting input. You need to close its input stream before you start reading its output, and you need to merge or read its standard error as well.

Answer (score -1):

This works fine.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new     ProcessBuilder(propertiesMap.get("PmdBatFile"));
File log = new File(propertiesMap.get("JenkinsLogs")+"\\"+"\JenkinsLog"+"_"+dateFormat.format(date)+".txt");
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
             processBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo(log));
Process process = processBuilder.start();
process.waitFor();
System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: There is nothing in the comments so far about exceptions, and nothing in this code about handling them either, but there is a remark about merging or reading the error stream.